# SVGs are not loaded with support library in devices with API<21

Tags: android, svg, android-support-library

Based on [the post in Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) I've added svg support:

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
       vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
}
```

also use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`

I'm using svg as `New`->`Vector Asset` and create a vector drawable 
and in the xml instead of `android:src` , i use to use the `app:srcCompat` attribute in ImageViews.

and i tried `setImageResource()` programmatically.

But the vector doesn't load in devices with API<21 (tried on 19) but loads on Nexus 5x(23).

Any solution here?

Answer (score 1):

What is the resource you are referencing in `srcCompat`?  An SVG?  If so, you can't do that. The support library doesn't add support for SVGs. It adds support for VectorDrawables to old versions of Android.

You have to convert your SVGs to VectorDrawables.  To do that, right-click on your `res` folder and do `New`->`Vector Asset` to import your SVG.

Note that the SVG convertor is not terribly sophisticated, and Vector Drawables only support a subset of SVG features.

If you really need to use SVGs, then you will have to use one of the third party libraries for rendering SVGs.

Comment: Of cource not. I'm using it as `New`->`Vector Asset` but no luck rendering it on older devices.